# EF replaces 'contains' operator with 'charindex' in raw sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, full-text-search

Because EF does not support full text search out of box (as i know) use sql command to execute query

```
var objctx = (ctx as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
                        query = objctx.CreateQuery<Candidate>(@"select 
                            c.CandidateId,
                            c.ProjectId,
                            c.CreateDate,
                            c.CreatedBy
                            c.DisplayName
                            from candidate as c
                        where (contains(c.DisplayName, @pattern))",
                            new ObjectParameter("pattern", displayNameFilter));
```

The problem came from where I even could not suppose.
EF, forming ultimate request, replaces operator `contains` with `charindex()` function wrapping in monstrously `case-when-bit-convert` construction.

What to do? How to force EF leave `contains` without being rewritten?

Comment: Why don't you write it as a lambda expression?

Comment: @GertArnold did not get your suggestion. Maybe provide some example?

Comment: I mean LINQ, the `Where` method.

Comment: @GertArnold so you want to say that EF supports Contains function in LinqToEntites and translates it to Contains clause?

Comment: Now I understand your confusion. What you execute there is not a SQL query but an *Entity SQL* query. It is translated similar to a LINQ query. You should use `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Candidate>`. (Which is in the answer, as I see now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = @"select c.CandidateId,c.ProjectId, c.CreateDate, c.CreatedBy c.DisplayName from candidate as c where (contains(c.DisplayName, @p0))";
var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, displayNameFilter).ToList();
```

Where `T` is your result type.

SqlQuery() docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx